# Match every row in a dataframe to each row in another dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, left-join

This might be a simple question, but I couldn't seem to find an obvious solution.

I have two data frames, df1 with 64 rows, and df2 with 662,343 rows. I join df1 to df2, where every row in df1 is mapped to each row in df2 so that I have 42,389,952 rows. df1 and df2 might look like this respectively:

df1:
|      Cancer      |     ID    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Sarcoma              |         3435      |
|         Leukemia         |         4465       |

df2:

| Gene |
| --- |
| TP53 |

new data frame :

| Cancer | ID | Gene |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sarcoma | 3435 | TP53 |
| Leukemia | 4465 | TP53 |

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You could use tidyverse: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html However there is no way to join tables if there is no field to link on. If in df2 there is only the Gene column, this can't work...

Comment: This is unclear. A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" without a clear, precise & full description elsewhere just means "unclearly". Your title suggests "cross join" but then you mention "left join". Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. [mre]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may `full_join` without any matching column.  So use `by = character()` in matching column argument.  Demo

```r
df <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2))

df2 <- data.frame(A = letters[1:3],
                  B = LETTERS[24:26])
df
#>   X
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
df2
#>   A B
#> 1 a X
#> 2 b Y
#> 3 c Z

dplyr::full_join(df2, df, by = character())
#>   A B X
#> 1 a X 1
#> 2 a X 2
#> 3 b Y 1
#> 4 b Y 2
#> 5 c Z 1
#> 6 c Z 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for cartesian product and not left join:

```
library(tidyr)
expand_grid(df1,df2)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Cancer      ID Gene 
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
1 Sarcoma   3425 TP53 
2 Leukemia  4465 TP53
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `merge`

```
merge(df2, df, all = TRUE)
```

-ouptut

```
A B X
1 a X 1
2 b Y 1
3 c Z 1
4 a X 2
5 b Y 2
6 c Z 2
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2))

df2 <- data.frame(A = letters[1:3],
                  B = LETTERS[24:26])
```